# Get number with this form \d\s\d\d\s\d

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the number `28` in the simple with this form integer+space+integer+integer+space+integerI have tried with this regular expresion  `\\s\\d\\d\\s` but I am getting  both number`11` and `28`

With this Expression `\\d\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d` I am getting this error  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 60 1"`.

The number should not have this form letter+space+integer+integer+space.

How can I fix it?

**Simple:**

```
ZOB/Hauptbahnhof Bussteig 11 20:04 20:34 28 21:08 21:40 22:08 22:40 23:08 23:40 00:30
```

**Code:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\s");
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\s\\d\\d\\s\\d");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());
    if (value != 10) {
        line = line.replace(m.group(), " ").replaceAll(" +", " ");
        writer.println("Min:" + value);

        // String line3 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(value
                + " has been found in this text document " + newName);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is just typo I corrected it

Comment: In that case, please spell check your questions before posting. If you don't show effort when posting questions here, why should be make the effort to answer them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lookarounds.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d\\s)\\d{2}(?=\\s\\d)");
```

This won't need any trimming of spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/5)

- `(?<=\\d\\s)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a digit and a space.
- `\d{2}` Exactly two digits.
- `(?=\\s\\d)` Asserts that the matched digits must be followed by a space and a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the pattern you try to match. This matches `4 60 1` as you outlined. The Problem is that you try to parse the *whole* match using `Integer.parseInt()` - and oviously that is no valid Integer.

Assuming, you would like to get the number `4601` as a result, you need to sanitize the input (remove whitespaces) before you can parse it:

```
value = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
```

Edit: On second read, your pattern seems to not provide the output you want, so this answer does not solve your *actual* problem.